# if condition is not working.when i try to execute if conditon,else is working

Tags: java, if-statement

what's wrong with this?
if condition is not executing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArmstrongNum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("ENTER THE NUMBER");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int temp = n;
        int rem = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        while (n != 0) {
            rem = n % 10;
            sum = sum + (rem * rem * rem);
            n = n / 10;

        }
        if (temp == n) {
            System.out.println("number is a AMSTRONG");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NUMBER IS NOT AMSTRONG");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `if (temp == sum) {` rather than `if (temp == n) {`

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong. `if(temp==n) {` is after `while(n!=0) {` so the only way it could be `true` is if `temp == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your Calcualtion is fine but your compare is wrong. For example the number 153, which is a armstrong number,  your variables will have the following values at the end of the loop:

- temp = 153
- rem = 1
- sum = 153
- n = 0

So you should not compare temp to n `temp == n` , how you currently do but temp to sum `temp == sum`

2. Also take in mind that your check will only work for three digits numbers, because your power is allways three. So for other armstrong numbers it simply won't work, for example:

54748 = 5<sup>5</sup> + 4<sup>5</sup> + 7<sup>5</sup> + 4<sup>5</sup> + 8<sup>5</sup> = 3125 + 1024 + 16807 + 1024 + 32768

In this solution i used the Math libary and the power but there are more ways if you don't like this to calc the length of an number

```
    public class ArmstrongNum {
    private static final Scanner SC = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static boolean isArmstrongNumber(int n){
        int temp = n;
        int rem;
        int length = (int) (Math.log10(n) + 1);
        int sum = 0;
        while (n != 0) {
            rem = n % 10;
            sum = sum + (int) Math.pow(rem, length);
            n = n / 10;
        }
        return temp == sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("ENTER THE NUMBER: ");
        int n = SC.nextInt();

        if (isArmstrongNumber(n)) {
            System.out.printf("%d is a Armstrong number", n);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%d is no Armstrong number", n);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try another way

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("ENTER THE NUMBER");
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            if (n == 0) {
                throw new Exception("Number is 0");
            }
            int sum = 0;
            String number = String.valueOf(n);
            char[] chars = number.toCharArray();
            double length = chars.length;
            for (char item : chars) {
                double result = Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(item)), length);
                sum = sum + (int) result;
            }

            if (sum == n ) {
                System.out.println("number is a AMSTRONG");}
            else {
                System.out.println("NUMBER IS NOT AMSTRONG");
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        }
    }
```